# Transpose: Array not outputting all results

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have written a script which scans through a worksheet called "Employee Placement" and searches for new employees to place into a sheet called "Rank".  The logic in my code states that if an employees name is found in Employee Placement, goto the rank tab and try to find it.

If it cannot be found, it puts the name into an array until the whole list is scanned, the results from the array are then to be put into the rank worksheet and then sorted alphabetically.

My code works, but when I did a test run, I had 95 entries in the array, and when it came to transposing the results onto the rank sheet, it can only transpose 16 entries.  Is there any reason why this is happening?  Maybe a limitation in the worksheet.transpose function?

Code is below

```
Option Explicit
Sub PopulateNewNames()

Dim M As Integer, EndOfMaster As Integer, NameCounter As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
Dim NameValue As String
Dim NewNames() As Variant

EndOfMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Employee Placement").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Rank = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rank").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
NameCounter = 0
ReDim NewNames(NameCounter)

With Sheets("Employee Placement")
    For M = 2 To EndOfMaster
        If .Range("A" & M).Value <> "" Then
           NameValue = .Range("A" & M).Value
           Sheets("Rank").Activate
           With Sheets("Rank")
                .Columns("A:A").Select
                Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:=NameValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
           If Cell Is Nothing Then
                ReDim Preserve NewNames(NameCounter)
                NewNames(NameCounter) = Sheets("employee placement").Range("A" & M).Value
                NameCounter = NameCounter + 1
           End If
           End With
        End If
    Next M
End With

'Take results in Array and put them into the last cell of the rank spreadsheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rank").Range("A" & Rank + 1 & ":A" & UBound(NewNames) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(NewNames)

End Sub
```

Comment: In that last line what is `Rank` ?  Where is its value coming from ?

Comment: Very very good spotting Tim, I think I know where the issue is now.  I just changed the transpose line and it fixed the issue, thank you!  New transpose line is as follows

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rank").Range("A" & Rank + 1 & ":A" & Rank + UBound(NewNames) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(NewNames)

Comment: You might find it easier to use `Resize()` there - `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rank").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(NewNames) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(NewNames)`